# Does this component fit into the Anti-Patterns of React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, anti-patterns

How can I rewrite this component so it doesn't go against the rules of React? I'm calling the function `renderButtonType()` inside of the `render()`. Is that the correct way to conditionally render the component or is there a better way?

```js
// Component: Button (Navigate)
const ButtonNavigate: React.FC<IProps> = (props): JSX.Element => {
  // Render Button Type
  const renderButtonType = (): JSX.Element | undefined => {
    // Add
    if (props.buttonType === 'Add') {
      return <Icon name="ios-add" color="#FFFFFF" size={defaultStyles.fontSizeTitle1} />;
    }
    // Filter
    else if (props.buttonType === 'Filter') {
      return <Icon name="ios-filter" color="#FFFFFF" size={defaultStyles.fontSizeHeading} />;
    }
    // Message
    else if (props.buttonType === 'Message') {
      return <Icon name="ios-create-outline" color="FFFFFF" size={defaultStyles.fontSizeTitle1} />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={props.darkMode ? styles.containerDark : styles.containerLight} onPress={props.onPress}>
      <>{renderButtonType()}</>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

**Edit: (Updated Code)**

```js
// Component: Button (Navigate)
const ButtonNavigate: React.FC<IProps> = (props): JSX.Element => {
  // Render Icon
  const renderIcon = (): 'ios-add' | 'ios-filter' | 'ios-create-outline' | Error => {
    // Add
    if (props.buttonType === 'Add') {
      return 'ios-add';
    }
    // Filter
    else if (props.buttonType === 'Filter') {
      return 'ios-filter';
    }
    // Message
    else if (props.buttonType === 'Message') {
      return 'ios-create-outline';
    }
    // Error
    else {
      throw new Error('Missing props.buttonType (Button Navigate)');
    }
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={props.darkMode ? styles.containerDark : styles.containerLight} onPress={props.onPress}>
      <Icon name={renderIcon()} color="#FFFFFF" size={defaultStyles.fontSizeTitle1} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Comment: Looks reasonable enough to me

Comment: Why can't you have `<Icon />` inside the return with conditional rendering

Comment: You don't even need a function to do that. You can just assign a `name` and a `size` variable and conditionally set their values, then use them to render the `Icon`.

Comment: just a small suggestion, create a hash of buttonType like ``` const buttonTypeInfo = {'Add' : { name:'ios-add', color:'', size:''}, 'Filter':{...}, 'Message':{...}}```. in render function just return Icon element as ``` <Icon name={buttonTypeInfo[props.buttonType]} .... />```

Comment: @K.vindi That is actually a great idea! It removed the unnecessary logic of duplicating the icon code.

Comment: Yeah, that's looking a lot better :-) Notice however that your original code has `defaultStyles.fontSizeHeading` as a special icon `size` in one case